# angular reactive form add FormArray inside a nested FormGroup inside another FormArray inside another FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created the nested FormGroup (questionnaire) which contains a FormArray (section) which contains another FormGroup (creatSection()) that contains another FormArray (question) in which we have another formgroup (creatQuestion()) in which we have another formarray(answer) that has a formgroup (creatAnswer())

Everything appears fine unless I want to add another question or another answer nothing the addSection works fine
so the creation is ok but the problem in the add.
what I'm thinking about is when you create a question it doesn't know to where it's going to be put in but I couldn't figure out how to fix it

my questionnaire.ts looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './questionnaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionnaire.component.css']
})
export class QuestionnaireComponent implements OnInit {
questionnaire:FormGroup;
section:FormArray; 
question:FormArray;
answer:FormArray;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.questionnaire=this.fb.group({ 
      questionnaireName: [''],      
      section : this.fb.array([this.creatSection()])
    })
  }

creatSection():FormGroup{
return this.fb.group({
 sectionName:[''],
 question:this.fb.array([this.creatQuestion()])
}) 
}

addSection(){
 this.section=this.questionnaire.get('section') as FormArray;
  this.section.push(this.creatSection());
}

creatQuestion():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    questionName:[''],
    type:[''],
    answer:this.fb.array([this.creatAnswer()])
  })
}

addQuestion(){
  this.question=this.creatSection().get('question') as FormArray;
  this.question.push(this.creatQuestion());
}

creatAnswer():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    id:[''],
    answerName:['']
  })
}

addAnswer(){
  this.answer=this.creatQuestion().get('answer') as FormArray;
  this.answer.push(this.creatAnswer());
}

onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.questionnaire.value); 
}

}
```

and the questionnaire.html is like this

```
<h1>questionnaire bla bla</h1>
<!-- <app-section></app-section> -->
<form [formGroup]="questionnaire" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="questionnaire..." formControlName="questionnaireName">
    <ng-container formArrayName="section">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let ques of questionnaire.get('section').controls;let i = index;">
        
            <input placeholder="section..." formControlName="sectionName" type="text">
            <button (click)="addSection()">add section</button>
            <ng-container formArrayName="question">
            <div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let sec of creatSection().get('question').controls;let j=index;">
                
                    <input placeholder="question..." formControlName="questionName" type="text">
                    <input placeholder="type..." formControlName="type" type="text">
                    <button (click)="addQuestion()">add question</button>
                    <ng-container formArrayName="answer">
                    <div [formGroupName]="k" *ngFor="let ans of creatQuestion().get('answer').controls;let k=index;">
                        
                            <input placeholder="réponse..." formControlName ="answerName" type="text">
                            <button (click)="addAnswer()">add answer</button>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>    
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{{questionnaire.value | json}}
```

Comment: what is not working? or be specific!

Comment: it doesn't add a new question nor a new answer

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale here's the link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vlvyq)

Answer (score 0):

First Don't call to creatSection() in the .html

```
//WRONG
<div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let sec of creatSection().get('question').controls;let j=index;">
//OK
<div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let sec of ques.get('question').controls;let j=index;">
```

Well you need pass as argument the "indexs" of the arrays (I called "clasic way"), but you can also pass the group of the array itself

```
<button (click)="addAnswer(i,j)">add answer</button>
//or
<button (click)="addAnswer(sec)">add answer</button>
```

In a "clasic"

```
addAnswer(i:number:j:number)
{
   const arraySection=((this.questionnaire.get('section') as FormArray)
   const groupQuestion=(arraySection.get('question') as FormArray).at(i)
   const arrayAnswer=groupQuestion.get('answer') as FormArray
   arrayAnswer.push(this.creatAnswer())
}
```

If you pass the array itself

```
addAnswer(groupQuestion:FormArray)
{
   const arrayAnswer=groupQuestion.get('answer') as FormArray
   arrayAnswer.push(this.creatAnswer())
}
```

NOTE: with a stackblitz was easer check and it's possible eror in my code, please get it the idea

Comment: that worked fine you've really saved me @Eliseo thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Eliseo the result would look like 
questionnaire.html

```
<h1>questionnaire bla bla</h1>
<form [formGroup]="questionnaire" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="questionnaire..." formControlName="questionnaireName">
    <ng-container formArrayName="section">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let ques of questionnaire.get('section').controls;let i = index;">

            <input placeholder="section..." formControlName="sectionName" type="text">
            <button (click)="addSection()">add section</button>
            <ng-container formArrayName="question">
            <div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let sec of ques.get('question').controls;let j=index;">

                    <input placeholder="question..." formControlName="questionName" type="text">
                    <input placeholder="type..." formControlName="type" type="text">
                    <button (click)="addQuestion(ques)">add question</button>
                    <ng-container formArrayName="answer">
                    <div [formGroupName]="k" *ngFor="let ans of sec.get('answer').controls;let k=index;">

                            <input placeholder="réponse..." formControlName ="answerName" type="text">
                            <button (click)="addAnswer(sec)">add answer</button>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>    
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{{questionnaire.value | json}}
```

and questionnaire.ts would look like this

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  questionnaire:FormGroup;
  section:FormArray;
  question:FormArray;
  answer:FormArray;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
 this.questionnaire=this.fb.group({ 
      questionnaireName: [''],      
      section : this.fb.array([this.creatSection()])
    })
  }
  creatSection():FormGroup{
return this.fb.group({
 sectionName:[''],
 question:this.fb.array([this.creatQuestion()])
}) 
}

addSection(){
 this.section=this.questionnaire.get('section') as FormArray;
  this.section.push(this.creatSection());
}

creatQuestion():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    questionName:[''],
    type:[''],
    answer:this.fb.array([this.creatAnswer()])
  })
}

addQuestion(groupSection:FormArray){
  const arrayQuestion=groupSection.get('question') as FormArray
  arrayQuestion.push(this.creatQuestion())
}

creatAnswer():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    id:[''],
    answerName:['']
  })
}

addAnswer(groupQuestion:FormArray){
    const arrayAnswer=groupQuestion.get('answer') as FormArray
  arrayAnswer.push(this.creatAnswer())
}

onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.questionnaire.value); 
}
}
```